# What is the best way to implement submission forms in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

What is the best way to implement submission forms in asp.net ?

i have to accept some values from user from four different pages and submit the contents as email..

which is the best method to do this ?

is this using masterpage or views or something else???

Note:i am not using any login controls in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these 4 pages a part of a wizard, where the user provides different inputs at each step in a process?  Or are the 4 pages unrelated, but share some common fields?

It depends on what your views will be doing.  If the user interface looks different from the rest of the site, a MasterPage would probably be appropriate.  However, if they share the same UI, you might consider combining the fields into a User Control that's used on all 4 views.

Use classes in the System.Net.Mail namespace to send the email messages.  Look up the MailMessage class in MSDN or just google it.